# Security alert dialogbox when launching arctoolbox

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arctoolbox, arccatalog

Every time I launch arctoolbox from arccatalog, the following dialog box appears:

[image]

Then, whatever I answer, it takes ages (~36s) before the box disappear and I can finally use arctoolbox. What could be done to remove that?

Comment: Define "ages". It takes a while (<15 sec) to load ArcToolbox for me too, and I don't get no message first.

Comment: I used my timer: It takes ~36s.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the web browser security settings, since ArcToolbox uses some activex controllers and I have seen issues related to activex and other web browser settings. http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/17068-Problem-running-any-tool

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks a lot for this link. Unfortunately, none of the tricks indicated on this page solved my problem.